# How to resize svg from a sprite

Tags: svg

I have an SVG sprite with several elements. I am using them as CSS backgrounds. I would like to use the elements in different sizes  without using JS. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an [SVG fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) to the URL with a viewBox e.g. MyDrawing.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,200,1000,1000))

This works in Firefox, support in other UAs may vary.